# Show preloader image when clicked on <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, preloader

I would like **all** HTML link (`<a href=...`) tag to show an image (GIF preloader) center of the screen when clicked. Currently, I have a code that shows a loading progress bar but it only shows when that page is loaded. I want the GIF preloader to show *immediately* after user clicked on a link.

What code and where do I need to add?

Comment: share your code on JsFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(e){
       $('<img src="image-pat/img.gif" class="image-loader"/>').appendTo('body');
       // ....
       // your code
       // ....
       if($('.image-loader').length) { // check length to remove image-loader again
          $('.image-loader').remove();// use, if you want to remove the loader again
       }
       return true;
    });
});
```

Comment: as far as i understood, The OP wants to show an image in the current page, while the next page is being loaded. won't this show image in the next page after its ready?

Comment: After the update, still how does this load another page while the loader is displayed?

Answer (score -1):

use jquery .imageloader()

```
<img class="img" src="image.png" />
<script>
$(function() {
$('.img').imageloader();
});
</script>
```

add the function to a button

Hope this helps.

Visit here for loads of examples.

[.imageloader()](http://beatak.github.io/jquery-imageloader/)

try this out

Answer (score -1):

You have to preload the image.
To do that, either create an image element and hide the image, only show on click.

OR

You can call createElement on the document ready function and set its source like below:

```
var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.setAttribute("src", "images/my_image.jpg");
```

Then, when you use that source elsewhere, it would show the image immediately as its already loaded by browser.

Comment: How will this show an image in the current page while another page is being loaded? by default when we click a hyperlink browser will start redirection process..

Comment: @TilwinJoy In that case, you can add a handler on click of anchor which removes/hides content and show a progress image, and then return true for the browser to continue loading the other page.